# PhotoView fit screen height maintain aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-photoview

I cant scaletype for my PhotoView that lets me pan side to side on an image while being full-screen, without cropping the sides using Photo.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP. How would I go about doing this?

This is what I want (where the user can pan side to side to view the whole image):
[image]

This is what I get (when using ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, which is closest to what I'm going for but because of the CROP, doesnt allow panning side to side.):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using a PhotoViewAttacher like this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
PhotoViewAttacher photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
photoViewAttacher.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
```

and then using an ImageView (id.preview) with the ScaleType in the XML set as Matrix. (otherwise it wont work)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a this [ImageViewZoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom).

if you don't want to  use lib see the codes and try to scale canvas

Comment: I tried using the library but it isn't the same, because once the photo is zoomed in, it can be zoomed back out. And the library codes didn't work either because they use the height of the image as a drawable, whereas I am just loading the image into the PhotoView using Glide. 

Thank you for sharing that library though, I think it could be part of making it work.