# How to maintain aspect ratio but resize background image to fit entire screen, even if it can't show the entire picture

Tags: html, css

I want to do something like this: [PhotoView fit screen height maintain aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114143/photoview-fit-screen-height-maintain-aspect-ratio) in CSS as shown in the first two pictures. The method i'm currently using, cover, gets silly while on mobile so that the background image covers only the above part, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnFoc.jpg).

How can i resize the image so that it keeps this aspect ratio, but covers the whole screen, even if it means cutting some of the picture out?

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS force image resize and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object-fit: cover` is the right thing to use for this. Your issue seems to lie within the container's height. Try setting a `min-height: 100vh;` for it?

Or, if that's not the case, please provide a working test-case of your code, so we can see what's actually going on.

Comment: Hi, this is an old post, but this was most likely the issue. If I had to replicate it today, I would probably have gone for dynamic resizing.